# Execute query update with form from a query

Tags: php

I am trying to create a button on my user list page to delete that row, or make that user an admin.

Here is the info for the user query and html:

```
    <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
      try
      {
      $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
      $result = $stmt->execute();
      }
      catch(PDOException $ex)
      {
      die("An Error has occured. Please contact the server administrator for assistance.");
      }             
      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    ?>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row) : ?>
    <?php
    if($row['usertype'] == 2) {
      $usertype = "<span style='color:#F7FE2E;'>Donator</span>";
    } elseif($row['usertype'] == 3) {
      $usertype = "<span style='color:red;'>Admin</span>";
    } elseif($row['usertype'] == 4) {
      $usertype = "<span style='color:orange;'>Owner</span>";
    } else {
      $usertype = "<span style='color:#585858;'>Normal</span>";
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <!--<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>-->
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td>
    <!--<td><?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td>-->
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['steamid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td>
    <td><?php echo $usertype?></td>
    <td><form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="admin" value="Promote" />
    </form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And the code where I prepare and execute my update query:

```
        if(!empty($_POST['admin']))
        {
            $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `usertype` = '3' WHERE `id` = " . $row['id'];
            // $query_params = array(':id' => $row['id']);
          try
          {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
          }
          catch(PDOException $ex)
          {
            die("An Error has occured. Please contact the server administrator for assistance.");
          }
        }
```

Unfortunately I when I run this current setup, it updates the very last row. To further ask what I am looking for, is I have a list of users:
where "admin_b" is a button that forced `$_POST['admin']`

1. Billy   `admin_b`
2. Bob     `admin_b`
3. Jill    `admin_b`
4. Jack    `admin_b`

UPDATE:

So in my form I have an input with `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $row['id']; ?>" />` and added this to my SQL `$query = "UPDATE users SET usertype = '3' WHERE id = :id";` `$query_params = array(':id' => $_POST['id']);`

`try
      {
      $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
      $result = $stmt->execute();
      }
      catch(PDOException $ex)
      {
      die("An Error has occured. Please contact the server administrator for assistance.");
      }`

Answer (score 1):

send an id with $_POST request, now you are always update user with id = $row['id']

```
WHERE `id` = " . $row['id'];
```

Comment: so I changed it to `$query = "UPDATES users SET usertype = '3' WHERE id = :id;` `$query_params = array(':id' => $_POST $row['id']);` But I also tried `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST($row['id'])` and none of it seemed to work. The ID will change based on what row it's in.         On the page, the there are multiple ID's that are displayed, as I am querying for all the users in my Database, but if I click on the button next to Billy, it would promote Billy to an admin from a normal user.

Comment: have you added <input name="id" value="$row['id'] - or whatever> ?
do you send id with POST query?

Answer (score 0):

```
row[id]edit?=edit.php= ...
```

and let's say you have list all the members and beside them is an href, the code above will execute, it will display let's say Billy?edit.php=1, wherein 1 is his primary key, then for the next, when you scroll the cursor to the next href of the next user, Jim, it will display, Jim?edit.php=2, in your edit.php,

```
if(isset($_POST['edit])){
code goes here to make the user an admin..
```

You can also make an href for the delete, similar to this edit..
This is just an idea/hint that I can give to you, but your problem can be solved in many different ways, it just depends on your approach on how you could do it :D goodluck.